# How do I request a package be upgraded?

Tags: package-management, updates, arduino

The Arduino support site has just released version 1.6 of their development environment.  The Muon repository only has 1:1.05.dfsg2 (which I have installed)

I have seen strong recommendations that I do NOT install software other than using Muon - so how do I request that the repository be upgraded to the current version?

Comment: Many thanks - I have filed a backport request.  I would comment that the process was QUITE opaque to one that is not normally a developer. I've had to spend quite a long time trying to figure out the way through the various links to get to the appropriate place....

Comment: I agree. The process to simply notify the right people that "There's a new version, it fixes critical bugs" is excessively cumbersome.  So I'm not going to waste hours trying to jump through the hoops, I'll just work around the out of date package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the update:

- If the new release fixes critical bugs, you can ask for a [Stable Release Update (SRU)](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Procedure).
- If the new release provides new features, but not fixes for critical bugs, you can ask for a [Backport](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuBackports).